# XML not been able to parse

Tags: php, xml

If I parse this URL in browser it gives me XML but When I put it in my code its showing empty array

```
https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20csv%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Ffinance.yahoo.com%2Fd%2Fquotes.csv%3Fe%3D.csv%26f%3Dc4l1%26s%3DUSDINR%3DX%2CTRYINR%3DX%2CSARINR%3DX%2CEURINR%3DX%22&diagnostics=true
```

My code is like this

```
public function fetch_Currency (){ 

            $this->url="https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20csv%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Ffinance.yahoo.com%2Fd%2Fquotes.csv%3Fe%3D.csv%26f%3Dc4l1%26s%3DUSDINR%3DX%2CTRYINR%3DX%2CSARINR%3DX%2CEURINR%3DX%22&diagnostics=true";
            $this->handle =  file_get_contents($this->url);

            if ($this->handle) {
                    $p = xml_parser_create();
                    xml_parse_into_struct($p, $this->result, $this->xml_val, $this->xml_index);
                    xml_parser_free($p);
        }
    }

public function get_exchange(){
        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($this->xml_val);
        echo "</pre>";
    }
```

Comment: Have you made any attempts to debug the script yet?

Comment: Have you tried [simplexml_load_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php)? It loads everything into an array making life easy :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres a simple way to parse the XML in your example, and get access to the elemnts:

```
$url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20csv%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Ffinance.yahoo.com%2Fd%2Fquotes.csv%3Fe%3D.csv%26f%3Dc4l1%26s%3DUSDINR%3DX%2CTRYINR%3DX%2CSARINR%3DX%2CEURINR%3DX%22&diagnostics=true";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

//echo first currency
echo $xml->results->row[0]->col1;

//whole document tree
print_r($xml);
```